# Как получить fragment из URL (то что после решётки) на сервере

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Помогите составить регулярное выражение.
У меня есть такое регулярное выражение `'~^/example/(\d+)$~'`, оно соответствует любой строке начинающейся с "/example/"и заканчивающейся числом. Мне нужно тоже самое, только чтобы вместо последнего слеша была решетка. Думал так будет работать `'~^/example#(\d+)$~'`, но нет, не пашет.

UPD:

1. Регулярное выражение успешно обрабатывает такую строку /example/2
2. Регулярное выражение должно находить все строки такого плана /example#2, /example#3,/example#425
3. Попробовал вместо слеша поставить \x23, не помогло

Возможно дело в том, что в коде они у меня вот так обрабатываются, это единая точка входа на сайте

```
 $this->controllerFound = false;
    foreach ($this->routes as $key=>$value){
        if(preg_match("$key", $this->request_URI,$matches)){
            include_once  ROOT.'/Controllers/'.$value['controller'].'.php';
            $Controller = new $value['controller']();
            array_shift($matches);
            $this->controllerFound  = call_user_func_array(array($Controller, $value['action']), $matches);
            if ( $this->controllerFound  == true) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

`$this->routes` это массив

```
$routes= array(
    '~^/$~' => array(
    'controller' => 'MainPagesController',
    'action' => 'homePage'
    ),
    '~^/list/(\w+)$~' => array(
        'controller' => 'MainPagesController',
        'action' => 'coursesListPage'
    ),
    '~^/course/(\d+)$~' => array(
        'controller' => 'MainPagesController',
        'action' => 'coursePage'
    ),
    '~^/example#(\d+)$~' => array(
    'controller' => 'MainPagesController',
    'action' => 'commentsPage'
    ),
    '~^/comments_jq~' => array(
        'controller' => 'MainPagesController',
        'action' => 'comments_jq'
    )
);
```

Comment: Используйте ascii-код - `#` = `\x23`

Comment: Приведите пример строки, пожалуйста. `^/example#(\d+)$` найдёт совпадение в `/example#123`.

Comment: Протестировать можно тут https://regex101.com/

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew слэш надо экранировать `^\/example#(\d+)$`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, обновил вопрос

Comment: @AndreyFedorov, обновил вопрос

Comment: @AndreyFedorov Не надо, т.к. знак разделителя тут `~`

Comment: @ShelterHolver `^\/example#(\d+)$` так что ли?

Comment: @AndreyFedorov, нет, не пашет, а зачем вы обратный слеш добавили? если взять вот это выражение ^/example#(\d+)$ и вместо решетки вставить например - или & , то все работает, как только ставлю # перестает работать. Может именно решетку нужно как-то экранировать?

Comment: @ShelterHolver попробуйте так `^/example\x23(\d+)$`

Comment: @AndreyFedorov, глухо, магия какая-то прям

Comment: @ShelterHolver слушайте, а так в принципе то можно, что бы регулярки были ключами?

Comment: @AndreyFedorov, в смысле ключами? в цикле? да, почему нет, это строки простые, которые потом в preg_match залетают

Comment: сложновато... я пас.

Comment: А вы уверены, что у вас на входе в скрипт есть эта решетка и символы после нее. Я так понимаю это url который вы получаете от клиента. Но браузер в любом случае будет передавать вам строку без # и всего что после нее, так как это метка, обрабатываемая только на клиенте и по стандартам HTTP она не должна передаваться на сервер

Comment: @Mike, вы правы! Оказывается решетки и всего что после нее тут нет $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']. Буду тогда что-то другое использовать, спасибо! Можете оформить как ответ, я отмечу его правильным.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никак. Тоесть напрямую никак. Он там не отразится, потому как он не передается серверу. Например так некоторые вэб приложения защищают ключи к апи. Самый простой вариант это вставить яваскрипт, который будет копировать якорь ( то что после # раньше было якорем) в куки или отправлять аяксом в отдельном запросе.